# Is this proof about $a^3>a \rightarrow a^5>a $ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Basically what I need is to know if this proof is correct.

what I need to prove is:$$a^3 > a \quad \implies \quad a^5>a.$$

So, what i did was this:
\begin{align*}
a^3 a^2 & > a a^2\\
\Rightarrow \quad a^5 & > a^3.
\end{align*}
Because $a^5>a^3$, I can say that $a^5>a$.

**EDIT:** $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, sorry I totally forgot to write it

Comment: It would be good to specify the context: Do you want a proof for the case that $a$ is a real number? Do you want it for the case of arbitrary [ordered fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)? If it's not the latter, tagging [tag:abstract-algebra] is perhaps not the most suitable tag. I guess [tag:algebra-precalculus] or [tag:inequality] would be better. \\ This in fact doesn't really matter to the way it's proved, but I think it's good to state your assumptions whenever you post a question.

Answer (score 6):

Looks ok to me. Since $a^2$ is positive no matter what, it doesn't change the sense of the inequality. And then you simply deduced from the fact $a^5 > a^3$ and $a^3 > a$ then $a^5 > a$. Looks ok to me. And it also seems kind of obvious that the answer is yes.

Comment: It may be true but I would say it is not totally obvious for negative $a$.

Comment: It doesn't even hold for negative a. If we take -2, we get $-8 > -2$ which is obviously false. That's because you're dealing with odd powers (where the sign counts). So, his proof is correct and the fact that $a^3 > a^1$ sort of implies you're dealing with $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: It does hold in $(-1,0)$ even if this is not obvious. For example $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \gt \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^5 \gt \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @andreas.vitikan: $a^{3}>a^{1}$ does not imply $a\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Consider e.g. $a=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now that I think of it, it implies that a is different than 0 and $a > -1$.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify this proof further, I would additionally say, given $a^3 > a$, that $a \ne 0$ and also that $a^2 \gt 0$.  This justifies the algebraic step of multiplying both sides of the inequality by $a^2$.

EDIT: This answer is completely different from my original one which was all wrong as pointed out by Henry.

Comment: As a counterexample $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \gt \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ but  $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \lt 1$.

Comment: @Henry, indeed.  The other answer nailed it, actually.  I'll delete this so as not to sow confusion once I recover from my embarrassment...

Answer (score 1):

How do you deduce $a^3a^2>aa^2$? You have to assume that $a^2>0$. You should either:

- separately consider the case $a=0$ (where of course $0^3\not>0$), or
- just deduce $a^3a^3 \geq aa^2$ (since $a^2\geq 0$) so $a^5\geq a^3 > a$.

Comment: Well, when $a = 0$ then simply everything is 0. 0 at any power except 0 is 0. But I don't think that's what they had in mind when they made the exercise and put it in the textbook.

Comment: But your solution should note that case anyway, that is how to make a complete proof.